# How to automate insert id into child table with new created id from parent

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

How to make as default insert with id_user into child user_id? I will make at once update without extra select and insert in my program. Is this possible?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id_user` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_user`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `scores` (
 `user_id` INT( 10 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0',
 `score` INT( 10 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY ( `user_id` ) REFERENCES  `users` ( `id_user` )
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE = INNODB;

INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES ('i am');

UPDATE scores SET score = '10' WHERE user_id = '1';
```

Comment: You can't insert into more than one table in a single statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understand the example. If you just inserted user number 1, how come there is a record in `scores` with `user_id = 1`?.

Anyway, If your question is **how to get the id of the user you just inserted** into `users` so you can insert a child record into `scores`, you can run

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

after the first insert, and use the result for the second insert (/update).